# laravel 4 Controller Route Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am very new to Laravel world and it is very interesting to explore this framework but on my journey I got stuck with this problem.

**Route**

```
Route::controller('rooms', 'RoomsController');
```

**Controller method**

```
public function postUpdate($id){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Room::$rules);
    $room = Room::find($id);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $room->name = Input::get('name');
        $room->description = Input::get('description');
        $room->facilities = Input::get('facilities');
        $room->info = Input::get('info');
        $room->price = Input::get('price');
        $room->beds = Input::get('beds');
        $room->no_of_rooms = Input::get('no_of_rooms');
        $room->hotel_id = Input::get('hotel_id');
        $room->save();
        return Redirect::to('hotels/view/'.$room->hotel_id)
        ->with('message', 'Room Created');
    }
    return Redirect::back()
    ->with('message', 'Something went Wrong')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

My problem is with opening a form. So can anyone help me with this problem

**Edit View**

```
{{ Form::model($room,array('route' => array('rooms.update', $room->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files'=>true)) }}
```

I am getting this error in `edit.blade.php`

> Route [rooms.update] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\HotelBookingApp\app\views\rooms\edit.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the controller as the routing mechanism. Try following:

```
{{ Form::model($room,array('action' => array('RoomsController@postUpdate',$room->id), 'method' => 'PUT',      'files'=>true)) }}
```

Comment: i tried this code before but i am getting **Controller method not found** Error. So any other suggestion plz?

Comment: Use this in your routes
    Route::resource("rooms","RoomsController");
controller is too ambiguous. Let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: its was not possible with Route::controller(); for me......so i used Route::resource(); like u said and its working.....But i still want to know possible methods using Route::controller();

Comment: the other possible way of doing it would be using the name of your controller in the route e.g Route::post('postUpdate','RoomsController@postUpdate') in your route instead of controller.